# How to simulate high video payload to benchmark an SSD?

Tags: benchmark, video-hosting, video, infiniband

I'm trying to evaluate some SSDs for a video on-demand use-case. We've done some benchmarking tests on them, but we'd like to get an idea of the number of video streams that they can support with a more realistic load test than typical benchmark tools.

So far, I've done this:

- fill the SSD with movie files
- remotely mount that SSD on other servers
- run a script from these other servers, that launches a bunch of VLC instances randomly on loop on one of these files. (NB: the VLC instances are running with the options `--vout dummy --aout dummy --codec dummy` so that it requests the file continuously, but doesn't do any decode on it to save on CPU)

I also have a settop box that decodes from that same SSD. The idea is to see if we can visually notice when the SSD performance starts to fall apart.

I'm getting decent results but the main problem is that the load servers hit a limit (in the 700-800 range with 10-12GB of RAM) in the number of streams they can grab. It looks like it's due to a lot of swapping happening all at once, pushing `iowait` sky high and making the server almost irresponsive.

To put it in a nutshell, my questions are:

- does that setup make sense?
- can you think of another way to do this?
- can you think of tweaks not to have the load servers become irresponsive after a certain number of streams? (I played a bit with `/proc/sys/vm/swappiness` but it didn't seem to make a difference)

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do video on demand systems and there's no substitute for actually writing a bit of code that accurately portrays real playback characteristics. We wrote one we call 'VODBasher', it uses the exact transport mechanism we really use on the real platform and we run it from real locations all over the place. This helped us understand where we were going to see problems and where we wouldn't. Anything else is jest guesswork.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My main goal is to get a gross idea of the capabilities to see if this solution would make any sense at all, so guesswork is fine for now. But I'll try to follow your advice and have real loads in real locations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty reasonable that you would in fact run out of ram on your "load servers" (acting as clients in this scenario) with 700-800 copies of VLC running. That's just 12-17MB of RAM used per instance, and there goes your 10-12GB. (So no wonder tweaking swappiness doesn't get you very far).

Is there any particular reason to really load the movie with vlc (even with dummy output), rather than just dumping it to `/dev/null`?

Comment: The reason why I went with VLC was to make sure that it would request the file continuously the most similar to a real scenario, rather than getting the file all at once as fast as the available bandwidth and IO permit. Good point on the RAM per instance.